# How to tint or alter the colour of a pattern in Inkscape?

Tags: color, inkscape, patterns

I am able to import and apply patterns to objects, but I don't know how to adjust the colour of the patterns.

How does one tint a pattern in Inkscape?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [create your own colorful pattern](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/TilePattern.html), but you can also simply change the color of the built-in patterns for your file.

For example, starting from a simple shape filled with a built-in pattern:

[image: shape with pattern]

You can change default color (black in the example) using `Extensions -> Color -> Replace color` command

[image: replace color menu]

In the pop-up windows you can replace the original color with your preferred one:

[image: replace color]

The work is done (this function change the stroke color too, you can arrange it later if needed):

[image: pattern color changed]

As you notice, this functions suffers from the absence of a color picker, but nowadays there is plenty of HTML color pickers for every operating system (and on-line too), so this is really no a problem.

If you want to change the color of a built-in `bitmap pattern`, you can use a [filter](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Filters-Preset.html).

For example, a starting shape filled:

[image: shape filled with bitmap pattern]

You can add a filter using `Filter -> Color -> Colorize`:

[image: shape to be filtered]

The fill is colorized, now, and you can tweak with the [Filter Editor](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Filter_Effects):

[image: shape filtered]

For example, you can change the default color, etc...

[image: default color changed]

Comment: Great, thanks that works for single-color patterns, but - what if there are many shades of grey (e.g. a rock texture?)

Comment: @jhtong I've update the note for the bitmap patterns. Hope it helps.